# How to use imported lib class in main app class - Android

Tags: android, reference, barcode-scanner, zbar

In the app i have created i imported a Lib called **ZBarScanner** https://github.com/dm77/ZBarScanner which i would like to call upon clicking button in the main app but i cant get reference to the class which am calling as indicated here [image: Error preview image]

How do we call imported Lib class in Android or what should i do?

EDIT.

> Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobiledatabook.com.qrdecoder"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: If your library is imported you should be able to add the missing imports in android studio by selecting the missing class name and pressing Ctrl + Intro (Command + Intro in mac os X).

Comment: cant resolve ZBarScannerActivity

Comment: Then your lib seems not to be imported

Comment: Have you check https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJrBF.png how the setup is looking?

Comment: or instead of importing the module i should move it to my app?

Comment: I have added the build.gradle

Comment: The `compile project` seems to be missing, check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Multi-project build, you should add the dependency of the other project in the build.gradle of the *app* file:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':zBarScannerLibrary')
    ...
}
```

More info [here](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/).

Comment: The lib is lacking documentation lots of things are missing but i manged to get it with your help... i can confirm your solution worked. I appreciated